# my la/ptop keeps on thi/nk/ing/ th/at I am hol/ding/ own the // k/e/y/////////////////////////////////

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

thi/s is relly g/etting/ in th/e way of thi/ng/s. It does it by it/self about /every thi/r/ty seconds/ or less, and goes on until a new key is h/it - several keys trig/g/er is /as well ing/lduing///
gh esc \ up //////////////////////////// th/ere are other k/eys which /trig/g/er it too. It is only ever/ the / it thinks is being held down. Sometimes it doesn't happen and everything seems to be fine for a while too. They keyboard is clean, nothing has been spilled on it either - my laptop thinks it is clean of virus' and that it's hardware is working fine.

I can ho/nestly say I'm/ at my wits end, because it h/appens so often I can'/t/ /even fix th/em fr/om my typing/. /////////

it/ //h/appened a few /month/s /a/g/o and th/en stopped f/o/r /a few month//s with/ no apparent cha/ng/e to anyth/ing/.

Comment: I assume you have performed a restart?  If that doesn't change anything.  You are going to have to remove and replace the keyboard.  If the restart does not help, then the problem you describe can only be a hardware, not software problem.

Comment: Have you tried another (USB) keyboard?

Comment: I have not restarted since the problem arose again, but it was restarted last time to no effect. It seems to be working fine right now, but it will probably restart playing up soon enough.
I have not tried a usb keyboard while there is still a problem I will do so next time I have access to one.

Comment: crumbs. it's always crumbs...

Comment: definitely nothing wrong with the keyboard physically as this was looked into last time this happened. I will try the suggestions from the other page aswell - however, int this case, it isn't a key getting "stuck" it's only ever the / and will happen after trigger keys, but also on it's own every few seconds. It's not happening now which is a blessing, though I don't know how long this graceful silence from the dreaded / will continue for.

Answer (score 0):

When it happens, try booting with a live disk or live usb of some linux distro. If it does the same thing, consider that proof that it is a hardware problem. If so, try blowing out the keyboard with canned air. If that doesn't work you could try more aggressive ways of cleaning the kb. You might break it but at this point, what have you got to lose? Very possible you'll have to replace the keyboard, but you might be lucky. Consider a keyboard condom to make this less likely to happen again soon.

Now it is POSSIBLE, although probably not terribly likely, that this might NOT be a hardware issue. I remember the FORM virus did something rather like this, issuing a caplock key signal at random intervals something like one day a month (it was a pretty benign, practical joke kind of virus). But, ten to one, your keyboard is dirty or worn out.